# how to create admin notification mail for newsletter subscription in magento

Tags: email, notifications, admin, subscription, newsletter

I am trying to create a module for magento 1.7 which will send a notification mail to admin whenever a new user subscribes to newsletter. I have succeeded so far in getting the mail sent. however, my code is not taking the getEmail and getId values to be displayed in the mail sent to admin. if anyone can throw some light on where i am going wrong, it would be great. here is the code:

**app/code/local/Notify/Biju/etc/config.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Notify_Biju>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Notify_Biju>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <Notify_Biju>
                <class>Notify_Biju_Model</class>
            </Notify_Biju>
        </models>
        <template>
            <email>
                <newsletter_alert_template translate="label" module="n">
                    <label>Newsletter Alert to Admin</label>
                    <file>newsletter_subscription_notify.html</file>
                    <type>html</type>
                </newsletter_alert_template>
            </email>
        </template>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <newsletter_subscriber_save_after>
                <observers>
                    <Notify_Biju_Model_Observer>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Notify_Biju_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>newsletteralert</method>
                    </Notify_Biju_Model_Observer>
                </observers>
            </newsletter_subscriber_save_after>
        </events>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/Notify/Biju/Model/Observer.php**

```
<?php

class Notify_Biju_Model_Observer {

    const XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE = 'newsletter_alert_template';

    public function newsletteralert($observer){

            $eventname=$observer->getEvent()->getName();
            $subscriber=$observer->getEvent()->getSubscriber();
            $email=$subscriber->getEmail();
            $id=$subscriber->getId();

            $emailtemplate=Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadDefault(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE);
            $sender=array();
            $sender['name']="admin";
            $sender['email']="biju@talkingpebbles.com";
            try{
            $emailtemplate->sendTransactional(
                    self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE,
                    $sender,
                    'biju@talkingpebbles.com, allen@compkraft.com', // email id of website/store admin
                    'admin',
                    array('subscirber'=>$subscriber)
                    );

            }
            catch(Mage_Core_Exception $e){
                // echo $e->getMessage();
                Mage::log($e->getMessage(),null,'newsletter.log');

            }

        }

}
```

**app/etc/modules/Notify_Biju.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Notify_Biju>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Notify_Biju>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**app/locale/en_US/template/email/newsletter_subscription_notify.html**

```
    <!--@subject  Newsletter Subscription Alert @-->

<body style="background:#F6F6F6; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; margin:0; padding:0;">
<div style="background:#F6F6F6; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; margin:0; padding:0;">

<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">

<tr>
    <td valign="top" style="padding:20px 0 20px 0">
    <!-- (header starts here) -->
    <table bgcolor="#FFFFFF" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" border="0" width="650" style="border:1px solid #E0E0E0;">
    <tr>
            <td valign="top">
                <h3 style="font-size:22px; font-weight:normal; line-height:22px; margin:0 0 11px 0;"></h3>
              </td>
              </tr>
    <tr>
      <td valign="top"><h3 style="font-size:22px; font-weight:normal; line-height:22px; margin:0 0 11px 0;">Dear Admin </h3>
        <p> Congratulations! A new subscriber has registered for Newsletter. Please login to the admin back-end to manage subscriptions.</p>
        <p>Subscriber Email: {{var subscriber.getEmail()}}</p>
        <p>Subscriber ID: {{var subscriber.getId()}}</p>
        <br>

    </tr>
              </table>
      </td>
              </tr>
              </table>
              </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo:

Search for `array('subscirber'=>$subscriber)`.

You have "subscriber" misspelled as "subscirber"

Answer (score 0):

To get the subscriber email value & id in observer,

```
$subscriber=$observer->getEvent()->getSubscriber() ;
       $email=$subscriber->getSubscriberEmail();
       $id=$subscriber->getSubscriberId();



$emailtemplate->sendTransactional(
                    XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE,
                     Mage::getStoreConfig(XML_PATH_CONFIRM_EMAIL_IDENTITY),
                    'sample@xyz.in', // email id of website/store admin
                    'admin',
                    array(
                    'subscriber_email'  => $email,
                    'subscriber_id' => $id
            )
```

Then in mail - add the variables like this instead of your lines

```
<p>Subscriber Email: {{var subscriber_email}}</p>
        <p>Subscriber ID: {{var subscriber_id}}</p>
```